# Spotlight preferences ignored

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have set Spotlight preferences to show System Preferences first, and not show Webpages:

[image]

and yet these seem to be ignored:

[image]

Specifically:

- the "top hit" is never a System Preference. (Although the first result after it always is, if relevant.)
- web searches are *always* included.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm using a recently updated Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of investigation, I realise this was mostly a misunderstanding:

- reordering the categories doesn't affect what gets chosen as "top hit"
- the "web searches" are not "web pages". Web searches are always shown.

So: Spotlight preferences are taken into account, they just don't affect those two things.